# updating data of a column with their respective id in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I had a database in my sql with a logtime column which is a timestamp variable type. I had to create a new column in the table and fill all of them up for which I used an update statement. By doing this it altered the logtime column to the current timestamp for all my rows. I do still have the sql statement for the insert into which is:

```
INSERT INTO `crm_logs` (`id`, `refno`, `agent_id`, `action`, `logtime`) VALUES
(1, 'LP44456', 57, 'Listing website status changed from Action to Publish. The listing ID is #1883.', '2019-10-20 11:21:27'),
```

And there are more than 500 insert values. So I want it so that I can update my current tables logtime values with the ones in this insert statement which are placed with thier respective id.

Comment: *By doing this it altered the logtime column to the current timestamp for all my rows.* Have you checked the table structure? maybe `logtime` has `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property?

Comment: @Akina yes, the default value is current_timestamp() and extra is ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). But now changing it wont help because the values have been altered. I need to alter them again with the insert statements I already have

Comment: Provide show create table, you can create another table `crm_logs1` like `crm_logs`, insert the data to `crm_logs1` and then update `crm_logs.logtime` based on `crm_logs1.logtime`

Comment: *yes, the default value is current_timestamp() and extra is ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()* This is why all values were altered. You should adjust the structure and remove ON UPDATE property before updation... now all data is lost, and it is unrecoverable except restoring from the backup if exists.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Okay so how do I make it so that all of crm_logs1 logtime get inserted into crm_logs with thier respective ids

Comment: @Akina the `OP` has the insert statement so it is not lost, yet. @Jay Vijay Mondi, as far as i understand you only need `id` and  `logtime`, anyway , first you have to alter table `crm_logs` and remove `ON UPDATE property before updation.` as @Akina suggested, then run `create table crm_logs1  like crm_logs;`. Change the table name in your insert statement then insert the data in  `crm_logs1`. In the end run `update crm_logs c inner join crm_logs1 c1 on c.id=c1.id set c.logtime =c1.logtime;`

Comment: @ErgestBasha Read carefully. "I had to create a new column in the table and fill all of them up for which I used **an update statement**."

Comment: @Akina, maybe I got it wrong. If it is so then the only way is the backup.

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes this statement worked perfectly thanks.